# Strange Eloquent behavior: doesn't work double if condition inside foreach

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have next code:

```
$list = SparePartApplicationPositionProvider::where('app_id',$app_id)->with(['provider','application_position'])->orderBy('apos_id')
->get();
```

It display providers by position, all works is good.

I would like change some value and in this case it works:

```
foreach ($list as $value) {
            if(($value->id > 3)){
                $value->enter_price=3141592;
            };
        }
```

But in this case it's doesnt work

```
    if($value->id > 3){

        if($value->application_position->id == 26){
           $value->application_position->name_detail='test';
       }

   };
```

It doesnt "see"  ($value->id > 3) condition, work only ($value->application_position->id == 26) condition. How to fix?

Comment: Is `SparePartApplicationPositionProvider`->`application_position` a one-to-one relationship, or one-to-many?

Comment: @aynber one-to-many)

Comment: You'll have to iterate through `$value->application_position` using a foreach. `application_position` will contain a Collection of objects instead of a single object.

Comment: I think you have to call it like this `$value->application_position()->id`

Comment: why not https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators
set Attribute for it or get

Answer (score 0):

In this case,

```
$value->application_position;
```

will try to access `application_position` from `$value` via magic. which will return null and therefor your `if` function will return false.

So what you need to do is call it like a function and access the `id` when you are looping through the collection

```
$value->application_position();
```

so your code should be like this

```
if($value->id > 3){
    $positions = $value->application_position();
    foreach($positions as $position){
        if($position->id == 26){
           $position->name_detail = 'test';
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for help. It's good idea but I got next error in this edits Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo::$id

Answer (score 0):

`application_position` is a collection of objects. You'll need to iterate through it to find the one with the id of 26.

```
if($value->id > 3){
    foreach($value->application_position as $position) {
       if($position->id == 26){
           $position->name_detail='test';
           $position->save(); // Don't forget to save, or else it won't update
       }
   }

};
```